# How to make uitextfield Circular?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want a circular `textField` to show number(count of peoples) inside the circular text box.

I have already tried `cornerRadius` and `CAShapeLayer` suggestions.

Comment: What you have tried ? Paste code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you ignored `cornerRadius`? The best solution will be the `cornerRadius` itself.

First of all set the `frame` of the textfield to square shape,where `width=height`.

```
[textField.layer setCornerRadius:CGRectGetWidth(textField.frame)/2];
[textField.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

This will surly makes a circular text field for you.

Comment: Thanks Brother!!! there was a mistake with the dimensions. so getting oval shape missed the point of equal height and width concept. silly mistake.

Comment: Good. Why cant you Mark it as write answer then?

Answer (score 2):

For circular textbox

- **Take `UIView`.**
- **Put `UITextField` in it.**
- **Make `UIView` circular by setting `cornerRadius`.**

Don't forget to set property clipToBounds of `UIView` to `YES`

OR

- Set equal height and width of `UITextField`
- And set key Path in **User Defined Runtime Attributes** as shown below

Remember that value of corner radius should be half of height in order to get circular textfield.

[image]